# Dynamic content dsplay in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

How to dynamically display the content of the textarea in another textarea  as the user id typing it .This shoud be done by using Javascript

Comment: Use a `keyup` event listener in the first textarea, and set the value of the second textarea.

Comment: SO isn't a free code-writing service. You need to make an attempt to solve it on your own. If you can't get it working, post your code and we'll show you where you went wrong.

Comment: barmar - sorry about not posting the code .. as this is a part of some secret mission...

Comment: Who is `bamer`? That's the worst misspelling of my name I've ever seen. To send someone a message, put `@` before their name, and then use the auto-completion so it's automatically spelled correctly.

Comment: sorry for the mistake .. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function majText(){
    document.getElementById("textarea2").value = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
}

<textarea id="textarea1" onKeyUp="majText()"></textarea>

<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

or this

```
function majText(value){
    document.getElementById("textarea2").value = value;
}

<textarea id="textarea1" onKeyUp="majText(this.value)"></textarea>

<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#TextArea1").keyup(function() { 
        $("#TextArea2").val($("#TextArea1").val());
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3Ldqzax9/

Comment: There's no mention of jQuery in the question.

Comment: @Barmar That doesn't necessarily mean it's not the right answer.